# DynamoDB UpdateExpression A=B+C+D with using single request

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

## Here are the problem

#### My data look like

The following data is already in the database
`{
  A:1,
  B:2,
  C:3,
  D:4,
  E:0
}`

---

#### Failed Update Expression

`set A = B + C + D`

#### DynamoDB Error

`ValidationException:
Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "+", near: "C + D"`

---

#### Failed Update Expression

`set E = B + C, A = E + D`

#### Result Error

A should be = 9

BUT!!!

In DynamoDB

E = 2 + 3, A = 0 + 4

and then A will be 4

---

#### Success Update Expression

First Request: `set E = B + C`
Second Request: `set A = A + E`
A = 9
Result is correct, but here are two update request.

---

### How to A = B + C + D in single request and do not need third attribute E?

Thank you.

Comment: A = B + C + D is not 10 but is 9!! You are not adding A at first. And what is it that you want exactly make the add operation at DB without explicity telling (without knowing) the current B C D values?  Cause your expression makes the operation with the client side values. You very well can add them and send the result to DB in this case

Comment: Thank you CanSahin. I fixed the result of A. The data was already in the database. I want update A to let the result of A in DB is equal to B + C + D.